# EF5 and DB2 9.1. Boolean undefined type error

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, db2

I have a WPF app that uses EF5 to query a DB2 9.1 mainframe database... Whenever I try to do something like the following, I get an error saying that "BOOLEAN" is an undefined type.

```
var cc = contents.Select(x => x.NDC).ToList();
var sched = (from s in ctx.Query<Data.Entities.DrugSched>()
                                 where s.State == App.State && cc.Contains(s.NDC)
                                 select s).ToList();
```

So DB2 apparently doesn't have a bool type... and It doesn't like the List.Contains() function.   I can break this query up and convert the first part to a list of objects and query that  with the Contains function... but that's a crappy solution.  Anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Boolean was added to v10(?)  of DB2 for LUW....still waiting for it on DB2 for i.  Not sure about DB2 for z/OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use DB2 10.5 on Mainframe, Booleans are not supported.